# Adding missing timesteps to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a timestamp column. For argument's sake, we can assume the distance between the timestamp of the first and second row is always the correct distance and all other rows should be equally spaced. I want to know how i can add a blank row for each missing timestep from the 2nd row until the last row, being able to adding multiple missing rows consecutively. I want to keep all the data i already have and just add blank rows where there is a missing timestep that should be nan for all columns except timestamp.

Comment: What is the reason you want to duplicate your index?

Comment: I have a timestalp feature that has some gaps. I just wanted blank rows for these

Answer (score 0):

I think a code snippet like this would work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Let's create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ts','Col2','Col3'])
df.ts = [pd.Timestamp('2017-01-24 13:03:12.000000'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-24 13:50:12.000000'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-24 16:07:40.000000')]
diff = df.ts.iloc[1]-df.ts.iloc[0] #the difference between first and second timestamps

print(df) #Dataframe before changes

index = 2
n_diff = df.ts.iloc[index]-df.ts.iloc[index-1]

while(n_diff>diff):
    new_ts = df.ts.iloc[index-1]+diff
    row = pd.DataFrame({"ts": new_ts, "Col2": np.nan, "Col3": np.nan }, index=[index+1])
    df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:index], row, df.iloc[index:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    index+=1
    n_diff = df.ts.iloc[index]-df.ts.iloc[index-1]

print(df) #Dataframe after adding new rows
```

The output is:

```
                   ts Col2 Col3
0 2017-01-24 13:03:12  NaN  NaN
1 2017-01-24 13:50:12  NaN  NaN
2 2017-01-24 16:07:40  NaN  NaN

                   ts Col2 Col3
0 2017-01-24 13:03:12  NaN  NaN
1 2017-01-24 13:50:12  NaN  NaN
2 2017-01-24 14:37:12  NaN  NaN
3 2017-01-24 15:24:12  NaN  NaN
4 2017-01-24 16:07:40  NaN  NaN
```